# [react-native]npm install warn require multiple version react

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native, npm-install

I'm running a react-native project,and it's package.json dependencies some third-part libraries,but maybe these libraries haven't update for a long time,they require different version of react.
When I npm install, I got warning below:

```
npm WARN react-native@0.43.3 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN native-base-shoutem-theme@0.1.0 requires a peer of react@>=15.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @shoutem/animation@0.8.10 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-static-container@1.0.1 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-test-renderer@15.4.2 requires a peer of react@^15.4.2 but none was installed.
```

I'm not sure npm could install multiple version in a single project.So how could I fix this problem?

Comment: AFAIK your only option is to modify the `package.json` of your dependencies so that they require a matching `react-native` version.